# Integration of Workflow Foundation

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

I'm building a web application which has some processing of user requests involved. A user submits request for something, it goes through few steps and departments and its status changes through some predefined statuses, in the organization before being approved or rejected. During processing the ball may roll back to the user's court for some changes or to update some information.
The client wants to user workflow to control the processing. Please let help me decide how I can integrate it with the application

Answer (score 0):

These are two references which might help you..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/wfstatemachineaspnet.aspx

http://odetocode.com/code/465.aspx

Comment: maybe you didn't get my idea, it's not a broad frequently topic.
My ASP.NET project is an archive system, which every document in it moves between many steps and statuses. the user of this system ( the employee ) should make this plan for the document using the WWF toolbox(he's not the designer to make it by code). so i want to make the Workfolw toolbox in employee's interface and using the sample tools  or another way giving him a the ability to make the document path.